# How to insert data in a column with a trigger after data is inserted in a row?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, triggers

I have a program  in Laravel where after users register they need a badge number, I want that  number to be generated randomly after they register in the database. I  should use triggers but  I struggle with syntax.

### users table

```
id bigint(20)
name varchar(255)
surname varchar(255)
nr_legitimatie varchar(255)
```

I want that 'nr_legitimatie' field to be unique.
This is what I tried but with no success

### Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER numar_leg
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    legitimatie VARCHAR(191)
BEGIN
    legitimatie =('
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num
    FROM numbers_mst
    WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT my_number FROM numbers_mst) 
    LIMIT 1' );
    set `users`.`nr_legitimatie` = legitimatie;
 END;
```

Comment: normally we would handle assignment of a value to a column in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. Seems like if we are keeping track of the random values that have been used, storing those in a table, seems like we would also want to store the new value that we are using for the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a MySQL `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that assigns a value to the `nr_legitimatie` column.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER numar_leg$$

CREATE TRIGGER numar_leg
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE li_nrn BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE li_cnt BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE li_cnt > 0 DO
       -- generate a new random number
       SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*99999) AS nrn INTO li_nrn;
       -- check if the new random number is already used 
       SELECT COUNT(1) INTO li_cnt FROM users u WHERE u.nr_legitimatie = li_nrn;
    END WHILE;
    SET NEW.nr_legitimatie := li_nrn;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that this does *not* guarantee that the value assigned to the `nr_legitimatie` will be unique, because the code in the trigger is subject to a race condition. There is potential for two (or more) simultaneous sessions to each discover the same random number is not yet "unused", and each session will use it. (The check for an existing value precedes the assignment to the column.)

If we want to guarantee uniqueness, we should add a UNIQUE constraint (UNIQUE KEY)  on the column in the `users` table.

We can also use a separate table to track the numbers that are used, with a UNIQUE constraint on the column, we can attempt inserts, and catch the error when an attempt to insert a duplicate is made.

If we introduce a tracking table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE nrn (nrn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY) ;
```

Then we can avoid the race condition, making the test for existing duplicate and reservation of the new value at the same time. Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER numar_leg
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE li_nrn BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE li_dup BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 SET li_dup := 1;
    WHILE li_dup > 0 DO
       SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*99999) AS nrn INTO li_nrn;
       SET li_dup := 0;
       INSERT INTO nrn (nrn) VALUES (li_nrn);
    END WHILE;
    SET NEW.nr_legitimatie := li_nrn;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The edge case here is the trigger is executed, a new random number is generated and reserved, but the insert into the `users` table fails for some reason, and we don't issue a ROLLBACK. If we issue a ROLLBACK, then our new random number reservation will also be rolled back (unless nrn is a MyISAM table).